# Shell script to ssh to machines.

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

Should be able to ssh from one VM to another or more other machines, but should not prompt for public key authentication. 
How to cover the prompt in automation using a shell script.

Comment: `ssh` never prompts for public key authentication. It prompts for password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kusalananda commented, SSH doesn't ask for "pubkey authentication". If you're using pubkey authentication, it asks for the password that protects the private key. In this case, you should remove the passphrase from the keys -- it's probably the simplest solution.

Comment: Or add the key to an SSH agent. (this question is likely a dupe, I'm looking into it now)